# Can I use Ruby's OptionParser to accept an arbitrary argument pattern?

Tags: ruby, command-line-arguments, optionparser

Let's say that I have a simple Ruby app where I want the first argument (if any) to specify the environment: `TEST`, `DEVELOPMENT` or `PRODUCTION` (with `DEVELOPMENT` being the default if no argument is given). For instance,

```
ruby myapp.rb test
```

would run it in `TEST` mode. Also, shorthands should be accepted, so that for instance

```
ruby myapp.rb t
```

would run the app in `TEST` mode and

```
ruby myapp.rb dev
```

would run it in `DEVELOPMENT` mode.

I'd like to use [OptionParser](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/classes/OptionParser.html), but it behaves very weirdly. If myapp.rb is

```
require 'optparse'

environment = 'DEVELOPMENT'
opts = OptionParser.new
opts.on('test')        { environment = 'TEST' }
opts.on('production')  { environment = 'PRODUCTION' }
opts.parse!(ARGV)
```

then environment becomes `PRODUCTION` no matter what arguments I pass; for some reason, `opts.on('production')` always executes its block. (It doesn't if I use a flag-style string like `'-production'` instead.) And there's no way I can see to have OptionParser look for strings starting with 't' rather than the exact string 'test'.

Maybe OptionParser is the wrong tool for the job. Obviously it would be trivial to split up ARGV myself. I'm just wondering what's going on with this behavior. I'm on Ruby 1.9.2.

Answer (score 1):

Provided you use the `parse!` method, any arguments handled by `opts.on` calls are stripped from the `ARGV` array *destructively*. This means that the original contents of the `ARGV` array will no longer contain those flags after the `parse!` method.

I recommend parsing the remaining set of arguments manually by comparing ARGV to an array containing 'test' and 'production'.

Check out the doc:
http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/OptionParser.html#method-i-parse-21

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you need to parse out arguments like that from ARGV before running OptionParser

e.g.

```
env = ARGV.select{|arg| arg =~ /dev/test/prod/i}.first
```

P.S. I'd recommend Trollop. I find it much simpler, and it's good about picking defaults.